# Salesforce communities : bug?

Tags: community, community-builder

I can not see the page structure and getting the JQuery error, anybody expirencing the same ?

[image]

> Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on draggable prior to
>   initialization; attempted to call method 'option' throws at
>   https://xxxx-dev-ed--sitestudio.na35.force.com/libraries/visualEditor:jQuery.js:20:275

Comment: Did salesforce move your org to a new instance? The na33 is a clue.

Comment: not that i know, its a free developer box i'm using.